# List index out of range though appearing not to be

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing

I wrote a simple program to check if strings are substrings of eachother. The issue is I keep getting a list index out of bounds error.

I tried printing i and j with each iteration and they never go out of the bounds of the list. I even tried to insert elements at s[5] and s[6] to check the index but still get the same error. What could be the cause of this error?

```
s = []                                        
s.insert(0,str("a b c"))
s.insert(1,str("a b c d"))
s.insert(2,str("a b"))
s.insert(3,str("b c"))
s.insert(4,str("d"))

j = 0
i = 0

while j < 5:
    if s[j] in s[i]:
        print("\"" + s[j] + "\" is in the string \"" + s[i] + "\"")
    i +=1
    if i == 5 and j < 4:
        j+=1
        i=0
```

This is my console output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
"a b c" is in the string "a b c"
  File "C:/Users/Kal/PycharmProjects/untitled/FSS2.py", line 16, in <module>
"a b c" is in the string "a b c d"
    if s[j] in s[i]:
"a b c d" is in the string "a b c d"
IndexError: list index out of range
"a b" is in the string "a b c"
"a b" is in the string "a b c d"
"a b" is in the string "a b"
"b c" is in the string "a b c"
"b c" is in the string "a b c d"
"b c" is in the string "b c"
"d" is in the string "a b c d"
"d" is in the string "d"

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Note that to add at the end of a list you should just `.append`.

Comment: `print(i, j)` at the start of you loop and it will be pretty clear. You should be checking `if i == 4 and j < 4:`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I tried using that check but I still get the same error

Comment: yep, should be `and j < 5`

Comment: The output I got without the error was what I was expecting, I made a silly mistake and it should have been j < 5 not j < 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the point when your code is raising the exception, the value of `i` is `5` and the value of `j` is 4. In your `print` statement you try to do `s[i]` i.e. `s[5]`and since max index of s is `4`, your code is raising `IndexError`.

I believe, in your code you need to do make modification in your `if` statement as:

```
if i == 5 and j < 5:  # Instead of j < 4
```

Then your code runs fine:

```
>>> while j < 5:
...     if s[j] in s[i]:
...         print("\"" + s[j] + "\" is in the string \"" + s[i] + "\"")
...     i +=1
...     if i == 5 and j < 5:
...         j+=1
...         i=0
... 
"a b c" is in the string "a b c"
"a b c" is in the string "a b c d"
"a b c d" is in the string "a b c d"
"a b" is in the string "a b c"
"a b" is in the string "a b c d"
"a b" is in the string "a b"
"b c" is in the string "a b c"
"b c" is in the string "a b c d"
"b c" is in the string "b c"
"d" is in the string "a b c d"
"d" is in the string "d"
```

Comment: If this is not the desired output, update the question with the output you desire. As it is hard for me to guess what your code is supposed to perform.

Comment: This is indeed the desired output (I was using it to fix logic errors for user input substring checker)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the line 18

```
s = []                                        
s.insert(0,str("a b c"))
s.insert(1,str("a b c d"))
s.insert(2,str("a b"))
s.insert(3,str("b c"))
s.insert(4,str("d"))
print(s)
j = 0
i = 0

while j < 5:
    if s[j] in s[i]:

        print("\"" + s[j] + "\" is in the string \"" + s[i] + "\"")
    i +=1
    if i == 5 and j < 4: <-- here
        j+=1
        i=0
```

At some point, your `i = 5` and `j = 4`, so the right side of this `if i == 5 and j < 4` statement is being False, and the `i` is not reseted to 0. So at the next loop, the `i` is equal to 5, and the maximum index is 4.

Better solution would be to use for loops.

```
s = []                                        
s.insert(0,str("a b c"))
s.insert(1,str("a b c d"))
s.insert(2,str("a b"))
s.insert(3,str("b c"))
s.insert(4,str("d"))
for i in range(len(s)):
   for j in range(len(s)):
       if s[i] in s[j]:
          print("\"" + s[i] + "\" is in the string \"" + s[j] + "\"")
```

## Edit to answer comment

```
s = []                                        
s.insert(0,str("a b c"))
s.insert(1,str("a b c d"))
s.insert(2,str("a b"))
s.insert(3,str("b c"))
s.insert(4,str("d"))
j = 0
i = 0

while j < len(s):
    if s[j] in s[i]:
        print("\"" + s[j] + "\" is in the string \"" + s[i] + "\"")
    i +=1
    if i == len(s):
       j+=1
       i=0
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can just use list comprehension and print the list at the end.

`["{0} is in the string {1}".format(s[j], s[i]) for i in range(len(s)) for j in range(len(s)) if s[j] in s[i]]`

Comment: There is a reason, why I'm not trying to completely change the code of someone who is learning. It's obvious that I know how to use list comprehension or use existing libraries, but the point is that he dosen't. I think it's better to do it this way.

Comment: Wasn't trying to say your solution was wrong - which is why I left a comment.  Just another way of doing it.

Comment: My concern with using for loops was that I need the index i to be 0 to check all elements (and I plan on adding to the code). Would it be poor practice to set i in a loop to -1 so it becomes index 0 with iteration?

Comment: There is no need for that. Let me edit my answer and show you how would it be to write proper `if` and `while` statements in the way you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to increase j only when i is already 5 (notice the `and` in the if-clause). Thus, when i=5 you are still in the while loop (which only depends on j) and you try to access s[i] = s[5] which is undefined.

Comment: Python is not Javascript, there is no undefined, it is an IndexError.

Comment: Right, yet I'm not saying that i[5] holds the value "undefined". Only that there is no value associated with it.

Comment: I did that so that each item is checked against the others. Shouldn't this be a non-issue since before i is used as an index it is reset to 0? Also when I added elements at s[5] and s[6] shouldn't this have gotten rid of the error?

Comment: @user6912880 the lists in python are indexed starting from 0. So the list with 5 items will have the maximum index equal to 4. Your `s` list had only 5 items, but you were trying to get something at the index 5. Adding one more item would allow that, but that's not the point in this case.

Comment: First, i is set to 0 only after you try to access it (that is before you even reach the if-clause). Secondly, you don't append ("add") any elements to `s` in the while/for loop – so the IndexError persists.

Answer (score 0):

Your i and j variables in while loop are incorrect. After changing values following code is working.

```
s = []                                        
s.insert(0,str("a b c"))
s.insert(1,str("a b c d"))
s.insert(2,str("a b"))
s.insert(3,str("b c"))
s.insert(4,str("d"))

print s

j = 0
i = 0

while j < 5:
    if s[j] in s[i]:
        print("\"" + s[j] + "\" is in the string \"" + s[i] + "\"")
    i +=1
    if i == 4 and j < 5:
        j+=1
        i=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your form it would be:

```
s = []                                        
s.insert(0,str("a b c"))
s.insert(1,str("a b c d"))
s.insert(2,str("a b"))
s.insert(3,str("b c"))
s.insert(4,str("d"))

j = 0
i = 0

while j < 5:
    if s[j] in s[i]:
        print("\"" + s[j] + "\" is in the string \"" + s[i] + "\"")
    i +=1
    if i == 5 and j <= 4:
        j+=1
        i=0
```

The error is in the 2nd if in your `while` loop. It should be `j <= 4` or `j < 5` in order to work.